# Wrapping text around float right

Tags: html, css

Hello I was creating a page and I can't seem to get something to work. I've got an image at the end of a paragraph, and in css this is floating right. I can't get the image to move up to be part of the paragraphy and then make the text wrap around it. [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/85e0brej/)

HTML

```
<p>
   TEXT GOES HERE
   <img src="src/src.jpg">
</p>
```

CSS

```
img{
   float:right;
}
```

Make sure to check out the JSfiddle because it has a better representation of what I want.

Comment: To be clear, you want the image to be in the bottom right hand corner of the page with the text wrapping around it instead of the image appearing below the last line of text.

Comment: @Marc Correct, bottom right with the bottom of the image with the bottom of the text. I might make a picture to display if confusion continues

Comment: It won't be an easy task, JS must be involved -  https://github.com/gilly3/lowFloat

Comment: As stated in some of the comments, the image has got to be moved into the text for the text to wrap around it.  This can't be done with current CSS, and even JavaScript would require a lot of work (see comment by @sdcr).  If this page is more or less static (even if loaded from a DB/CMS), the it would be easier to move the image into the text until you got the text to wrap as you need it.  In automated websites, you would rarely see this type of layout requirement since it is hard to realize.

Comment: @sdcr The jQuery plug-in does the trick, and also demonstrates the complexity involved.

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to move the image above the text for the float right to work in that way.

```
<p>
   <img src="src/src.jpg">

   TEXT GOES HERE
</p>
```

Comment: But the text is really long and I want it to be at the bottom. Will this still work. You can see the live example of what I mean at http://repmofbla.com/SimmonsRedone/biographyHTML.html.

Comment: HTML works in a basic stacking order from top to bottom, so with the image below the text and adding a `float: right;` to it will make it float to the right but there isn't anything below the image to move up into that empty space.

Comment: You could however place the image a few paragraphs before the end of the text

Comment: The problem with that is I'm going to be loading the text from a db with PHP so I'm not sure I would trust my programming skills to properly place that xD

Comment: then that is a big problem and no, you can't do it any other way using css

Answer (score 2):

You must either move the image to front or move it outside:

```
<p>
   <img src="src/src.jpg">
   TEXT GOES HERE
</p>
```

or

```
   <img src="src/src.jpg">
<p>

   TEXT GOES HERE
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aaron is correct, the image will have to go above the text. If it is long you can always do a

```
<p>
  TEXT GOES HERE<br>
  <img src="src/src.jpg">
  TEXT GOES HERE
</p>
```

Not sure if this is kosher with coding but it works.

Answer (score -2):

Put a `<div>` inside your paragraph and keep your text inside it. Then make  as `float: left` and your image `float: right`

Something like below:

**HTML code** sample **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chandansharma/85e0brej/2/)**

```
<p>
    <div> THIS IS A LOT OF TEXT 
           ........................
           .........................
    </div>
    <!-- MOVE THIS IMAGE UP SO IT'S NOT BELOW AND WRAP TEXT AROUND IT -->
    <img src="..Troll-face.png" />
</p>
```

**CSS**

```
img{
    float:right;
    width:150px;
}

p {
    width:100%;
    height: auto;
}

div{
    width:70%;
    height:auto;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Semantics aside, the image is still not where the OP wants it and the text does not wrap about it...